# Using pandas to save csv files with extended ascii separators

Tags: python, pandas, ascii

I have a file that is riddled with almost all basic ascii characters, and therefore, to convert it to a meaningful csv to be imported by our database, I have changed my computers default list seperator to ¬ (alt+170).

If I use excel to open an xlsx, and then save as a csv, the program does fine.  However, if I read a xlsx or csv into `pandas`, then call (the code below), it creates a file with two characters in place of ¬.

```
dataframe.to_csv(filepath, sep = '¬', index = False)
```

Opening these files as ¬ separated does not work and editing them in notepad shows me extended ascii character 182, as seen here: 
https://theasciicode.com.ar/extended-ascii-code/letter-a-circumflex-accent-ascii-code-182.html

How can I get it to save extended ascii properly using `pandas`?

Comment: did you try: `encoding='utf-8'`

Answer (score 1):

use the python unicode characters to solve this issue

```
import pandas as pd 
df = pd.DataFrame({'column_1':['a','a','a','a','a','a','b','b','b','b','b','b','b','b','b','c','c','d','d']
                   ,'column_2':[1,1,1,2,2,2,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,1,2,2,3]
                  })

df.to_csv('test.csv', sep = u'\xac', index = False)
```

Now here the u'\xac' is the unicode for the logical not operator

and to read it again

```
df2 = pd.read_csv('test.csv', sep = u'\xac')
```

This should fix your problem as you have a data frame that you can read and write using the character you need, this is all in the UTF-8 encoding.  If you want to use another encoding it is up to you.

BTW this is where I get my encoding mappings https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00ac/index.htm

Comment: so, i accepted this answer because it appears fine in notepad, but upon running my import tools again, the import tools, and excel, both see the other character.  What ive reverted to instead was opening the file in excel with python dispatch, then saving it as fileformat 6 with the region and language list seperator to ¬